# Angular 11 not applying multiple transitions with different states

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, animation

I'm trying to create an animation of a card with multiple children inside where every child has it's own enter animation. I am new in animation with angular, so what I thought was to create different states in the same trigger, for every child in the main div.

This is the typescript code for the animation:

```
    animations: [
        trigger('select', [
            state('selected', style({
                transform: 'scale(1.2)',
                marginLeft: '60px',
                marginRight: '60px'
            })),
            state('unselected', style({
                transform: '*',
                marginLeft: '*',
                marginRight: '*'
            })),
            state('visible', style({
                opacity: '1'
            })),
            state('hidden', style({
                opacity: '0'
            })),
            transition('visible <=> hidden', [
                animate('200ms ease-in-out')
            ]),
            transition('selected <=> unselected', [
                animate('100ms ease-in-out')
            ])
        ])
    ]
```

And this is how I bound it to the html:

```
<div id="game-box" [@select]="isSelected ? 'selected' : 'unselected'">
    <div id="game-box__rounded">
        <img [@select]="isSelected ? 'visible' : 'hidden'" [src]="icon()" alt="">
        <label *ngIf="isSelected" for="">{{ name() }}</label>
    </div>
    <span class="background" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + background() + ')'}"></span>
</div>
```

What I expect to see is the main div to zoom and simultaneously the img to appear with a fade animation.
What actually happen is that the image appear, so the **opacity: 1** is being applied, but only the transition **visible <=> hidden** actually works, the img suddenly appear and the **selected <=> unselected** transition it's like not recognized. What confuse me, is that if I remove the **visible <=> hidden** transition, leaving only **selected <=> unselected**, it actually works. What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out. After some research I found that angular, for some reason, when a component is animated, block the animation of the children, unless you use the `animateChild()` api. So i created multiple triggers for every child and I changed the transition **unselected <=> selected** code like so:

```
transition('unselected <=> selected', [
    group([
        query('@icon', animateChild()),
        query('@title', animateChild()),
        query('@background', animateChild()),
        animate('200ms ease-in-out')
    ])
])
```

As you can see i specified with `query()` the trigger of the child I want to animate, and the api `animateChild()`. For clarifications read https://angular.io/api/animations/animateChild.